# C3.js Change Legend Marker to Circle?

Tags: nvd3.js, c3.js

I am comparing C3 to NVD3.

I really like the legend function of the NVD3. The C3 legend is boring.

How can I change the legend to a Circle with the C3?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about a **pure CSS** solution?

```
.c3-legend-item-tile {
  shape-rendering: auto;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-dasharray: 0.1 10;
  stroke-width: 8;
  transform: translate(6px, 1px);
}
```

See in action: https://jsfiddle.net/Dimmy/40cubjve/

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by selecting the correct elements and changing their css code ([it's in the docs](https://c3js.org/samples/legend_custom.html)).
Use d3 select function to select all the hierarchy you need:

```
d3.select('.container').insert('div', '.chart').attr('class', 'legend').selectAll('span')
```

You can see some other nice example right here:
https://codepen.io/lucusc/pen/GZXBxX

But basically, go for the **legend** element and customize as you wish.